# How many 5-digit phone numbers can be created that don't end in 0?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am teaching myself discrete math from a textbook I picked up and unfortunately don't have a teacher to relay questions to. I made up an example problem for myself and was curious if my logic (and answer) are correct?

"How many 5-digit phone numbers can be created that don't end in 0?"

The set of possible numbers for each digit is ${0,1,2,3....9}$, which has a size of $n=10$.
We need 5 of these, so that would be $10^5$.
But of course, we need to make sure that last of these doesn't include 0.

Thus the answer: **$10^4 * 9 = 90,000$ possible phone numbers**

Can also be written as: **$10^5 - 10^4$**

Comment: Yes your answer is correct, that's called complement rule, do you require anything else?

Comment: No that is all, thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Is the leading digit allowed to be zero? You're calling them "phone numbers" so probably it is, but just checking.